# TypeScript: constant object derived from a union and specify allowable subsets

Tags: typescript

I am trying to replace an enum that was using hard-coded string values, with a constant object that uses string values from a union.

I would like to be able to specify subsets of the union that are allowable in certain contexts.

```
// The previous enum
// The values are the API routes
enum WordTypesEnum {
  Curriculum = "curriculum",
  Departments = "departments",
  VerticalGroups = "vertical-groups",
  Authors = "authors",
  YearGroups = "year-groups"
}

// The union supplied by the backend schema. The goal is to replace the enum with an object
// that can use the values from this union.
type GeneratedWordStoreTypes = "curriculum" | "departments" | "vertical-groups" | "year-groups" | "authors";

// /**
//  * A non-working as const solution using a Record
//  */
// const WordStoreTypes: Record<GeneratedWordStoreTypes, GeneratedWordStoreTypes> = {
//   "vertical-groups": "vertical-groups",
//   "departments": "departments",
//   "authors": "authors",
//   "curriculum": "curriculum",
//   "year-groups": "year-groups",
// } as const

/**
 * This works when picking out the subsets, but is not using the generated types in construction.
 */
const WordStoreTypes = {
  "vertical-groups": "vertical-groups",
  "departments": "departments",
  "authors": "authors",
  "curriculum": "curriculum",
  "year-groups": "year-groups",
} as const

const subsetOfAllowedTypes = [
    "authors"
] as const;

type AllowedWordTypeType = typeof subsetOfAllowedTypes[number];

// This should be allowed by ts
const validConstrainedType: AllowedWordTypeType = WordStoreTypes.authors;
// This should cause a ts error
const invalidConstrainedType: AllowedWordTypeType = WordStoreTypes.curriculum;
```

This code is also on [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUAsFNQBwE7QG4EsD2BXAzqaA7TAWwFgAoECGUZAQwBtNpdalQAXagQQAUBJUAiztm5AsVAB1dAgAm4AJ5xmAUUJFQAb3KhQAYUwIEqAMaZGGgLygARGaOnzxGwBodoACLQ4rdkQLsuNY2st6%20-viBru4AatAI7KYMAOJCmHBBtsjxiSYMALQA5mkZ0WS6XJicMpk2tFWQNWW6AJrQrKlYGaDBCu0IRSXYNuQAvuTklFCwmPgY%20KDY6XD0qNCyoABGChzUm7QmANYEG9gmMES0AHRUsIXoDKCouOzogt70B7CcsOIaAO6oTigWgLdCbABW0BM7EmYE4tHYoDyCxw32odEYzFAADMhBpOM9QLN5ldyOwlLBkgR4oj1tI5ABlV5IRTKWr2YxmCw2UAAH1soR8CQiUX5WRySXogy6w3FNj6rBl6TlArqDSaAG4JhQwMAAFT6uG6fWgLigfDofD5f4yQ6ofCFEG4ExW7BI7DoRiJK3E7AOp20UAAJWhMlkxtA%20uAxtd%20HdUnDzJk0DZzAAXCGw3IADzU-C0kSyBmyZOsynYFygfOF%20lJlmpisAPh6WkjEoSUuVpUzNmynby0uKsrKlF0ITCIoCw17QvC09HYHH9WqCBnthXjTXi90tk5jh5vf33Ocbl1u4V-W768vSuHKp3o2dyLdsLIk0NOlNUCJtoQh1wf4YAWOBTHtR1QGEXZYCWTZsGgQIq02KonlwS0kRwANoNAQoaQQOkNgpdkngWON3QQTAYVJL8YzIMikRLMtG2I6xtHKDtcgKe8ew4rtuOGM9xznKdIhvYS-AXQSNw1bde03JopLsQwuScIgbCPZSD1PdxbwGfj1NsRU9KGMon1oF1Xx1ejFkwOCEIAeRxLh6HodB-nWNNMgAbXIABIdVV2GcgAF1n3o7V3zIIjYGc1z3OLcM0zTVtovQHEbLs9hHNityPIrLz1E2eJgoi40f1wbBGnMDYipBFzcpqnZAnIazMVQWQ9FffCHTy5RMxy%20KSySylW0YhtPKueS1wiqZICJSqsHoDY8jREEOFweIhAQFrXxItqOq62gevkSl%20vqwbEspZLrDGlMJuPVTNSAA)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w8XJ4w) what you're looking for? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes this works. I didn't know about specifying the key index as also the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the backend types change this will throw an error:

```
   type ConstFromGeneratedTypes = { [K in GeneratedWordStoreTypes]: K }
    
    const WordTypesConst: ConstFromGeneratedTypes = {
        "curriculum": "curriculum",
        "departments": "departments",
        "vertical-groups": "vertical-groups",
        "authors": "authors",
        "year-groups": "year-groups"
    }
```

to select a subset use this type:

```
type AllowedWordType = Extract<GeneratedWordStoreTypes, "authors">
```

hope this is what you are looking for.